# cannot create iboutlet in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

i would just want to ask why i cannot create an iboutlet (e.g. UITableView). I copied a nib file, the .h and .m file from my different project(since I need them). After that, I renamed the .h, .m and the nib file. Then when I am going to add or connect IBOutlets to it, I can't. Why? Does someone know how to fix it? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you need to provide a new class name which the xib refers to (as you said you renamed it)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe You forgot change class name in .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps for renaming .h,.m and xib files. This will be Helpful for you.

1) Go to the header file `eg. MyViewController.h.`

2) Right click on your class name `eg. Right click on MyViewController.`

3) Select Refactor -> Rename.

4) Write New Name `eg. MyViewController1`.

5) Preview and Save.

This will rename your `Old class name` with `New Class name` from everywhere.

And Also check File Owner's Custom class property under `Identity Inspector` Section is the same as `New Class name`